# Uploaded images does not show when fetching data from MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website where user login to dashboard using PHP sessions and they can upload images. Then another user login the dashboard and view the images. My image are uploaded in a folder called "Upload" using MySQL database.

My image upload code is:

```
<?php
    include("config.php");

    if(isset($_POST['but_upload'])){

        $username = $userRow['username'];
        $email = $userRow['email'];
        $name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $target_dir = "upload/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

        // Select file type
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        // Valid file extensions
        $extensions_arr = array("jpg","jpeg","png","gif");

        // Check extension
        if( in_array($imageFileType,$extensions_arr) ){

            // Convert to base64 
            $image_base64 = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']) );
            $image = 'data:image/'.$imageFileType.';base64,'.$image_base64;

            // Insert record
            $query = "insert into images(name,image,username,email) values('".$name."','".$image."','".$username."','".$email."')";

            mysqli_query($con,$query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

            // Upload file
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'upload/'.$name);

    }

}
?>
```

My database table

```
    CREATE TABLE `images` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    `image` longtext NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Image upload part is working fine but when I want to display that image to another user. No image is showing now.

My image display code:

```
 <?php
    include("dbconnect.php");
    $sql="SELECT*FROM images";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($count==0){
    echo "No Image Found";
    }else{
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
    <img src="../user/upload/"<?php echo $row['name'];?>"> } ?>
```

Comment: php should be responsible for storing the image in this folder, creating a href for this image and storing that href to the database.

Comment: It seems you mix two approaches: storing image on the disk (is what your display code expects) or as a binary data in database (which your storing code does). Choose either one and go with it, do not try to mix the unmixable.

Answer (score 0):

Not real answer, but including advice how to fix and secure it.

Make use of mysqli placeholdes, other way your code easy to crack.

Escape file name with something like preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]+.[^A-Za-z0-9_]+/', '', $name);

As you said - upload working fine, so run image display php file, check html source and find whats wrong in image name or path.

As in above comments "store href in database", dont follow, you may change path, or some thing else, better place for path in constant/config.

One more, thing, may be error in username when you trying to display image:

```
<?php
    ... old code
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){?>
    <img src="../<?php echo $row['username'];?>/upload/"<?php echo $row['name'];?>"> } ?>
```